# Is there a shorthand for the previous version of a file in Git?

Tags: git

What I want is something like -
    `git checkout FHEAD~ path/filename`

What I currently do is find the previous version of the file via -
    `git log -1 --skip=1 path/filename`

and then,
    `git checkout <previous-commit-hash> path/filename`

Comment: What are you asking here? An alias for checking out the version of a file that is recorded in a parent of `HEAD`? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, what is `FHEAD`?

Comment: @Jubobs The question seems clear enough to me: find the previous version of a specific file, where "previous" means "the way it was just before the last commit that changed that file" (and ignoring other commits that don't change that file).

Comment: @hvd It makes sense now that you've spelled it out.

Comment: @Jubobs : `FHEAD~ == git log -1 --skip=1 --format=%H path/filename`.  
FHEAD in my mind should be the alias which stands for File HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial example of an alias to retrieve the previous version of a file.

The trick here is to format the log output with --format to only return the commit hash

```
[alias]
    prev    = "!f(){ git checkout $(git log -1 --format="%H" --skip=1 -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}/$1) -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}/$1; git reset ${GIT_PREFIX:-}/$1; }; f"
```

The use of `git log -1` ensures that `git prev` always returns the immediate parent file. Selecting the next parent can be more complex.

Note also that the file, once checked out, is immediately added to the index. It is not merged into your existing copy, and does not warn about overwriting local changes. I've included a call to git-reset to ensure the checkout out file is in the working directory only, and not in the index.

The use of `GIT_PREFIX` allows you to enter relative paths, though only relatively recent versions of git support GIT_PREFIX.

edit..

Same thing using git rev-list.. a very powerful git command designed for traversing git ancestry graphs when scripting and automating...

```
[alias]
    prev    = "!f(){ git checkout $(git rev-list --max-count=1 --skip=1 HEAD --  ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}/$1) -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}/$1; git reset ${GIT_PREFIX:-}/$1; }; f"
```

Comment: Or use `rev-list` instead of `log` for scripting!

Comment: Sure, why not. 
`git rev-list --max-count=1 --skip=1 HEAD -- ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}/$1` can replace the git log and produce the same result.